# Can't call soap metod from SoapEngine to Java Soap WebService

Tags: java, swift, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a problem with me web service which I created in Java. This web service is to send data to my mobile application created in Swift.

For now I just want to test communication between application and WebService, so I create one simple method which returns a string.

My WebService:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "mSetiWebService", targetNamespace = "http://javawebservices.dawidratajczak.pl")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class mSetiWebService {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getMyOtherStuff", action="getMyOtherStuffAction")
    public String getMyOtherStuff() {
        return "Hello from WebService !";
    }
}
```

The java package(namespace) name is `pl.dawidratajczak.webservices`. I test this WebService by `Boomerang Plugin` for chrome and it works fine. But when I use `SOAPEngine` for Swift a get an error.

My Swift code:

```
let soap = SOAPEngine()
soap.userAgent = "SOAPEngine"
soap.actionNamespaceSlash = true
soap.version = SOAPVersion.VERSION_1_1
soap.responseHeader = true // use only for non standard MS-SOAP service

soap.requestURL("http://localhost:8080/mSetiSoapService/mSetiWebService",
                soapAction: "getMyOtherStuff",
                completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int,
                    dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in

                    let result:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
                    NSLog("%@", result)

    }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

  NSLog("%@", error)
}
```

The error is simple: (I change . in address to _)

> SOAPEngine Server response: Unexpected wrapper element getMyOtherStuff found.   Expected {[httpjavawebservices_dawidratajczak_pl}getMyOtherStuff.
>   2016-08-26 20:24:59.835 SETI Mobile[4658:200526] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=0 "Unexpected wrapper element getMyOtherStuff found.   Expected {http://javawebservices_dawidratajczak_pl}getMyOtherStuff." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected wrapper element getMyOtherStuff found.   Expected {javawebservices_dawidratajczak_pl}getMyOtherStuff.}**

When I put the `soapAction` like the error expect `{url}getMyOtherStuff` I get another error that character `{` is unrecognized. At the end when I put all url and `soapActionme` function is not found.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Your Java web service is expecting a target namespace (declared in the annotation), but the document that SOAPEngine is sending clearly does not include the same namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can add this in SOAPEngine?

Comment: you have the WSDL declaration ? You can see many examples of SOAPEngine from the site GitHub https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine